# How can I override the selected font color of mui/material/Tab' (react)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The blue color should be red.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xtjJ.png)

```
 <Tabs  
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                textColor="primary"
                indicatorColor="primary"
                variant="scrollable"
                scrollButtons="auto"
                aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
                TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "red" , color: "red" }}}
            >
                {
                    this.props.tabs.map(tab => {
                        return <Tab     label={tab.label} {...this.a11yProps(tab.index)} />
                    })
                }

            </Tabs>
```

The red line working with TabIndicatorProps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

You can set `textColor` prop on `Tabs` if your theme secondary color is red.

```js
<Tabs textColor="secondary"></Tabs>
```

Or you can customize styling of a `Tab` if you want a custom color.

```js
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledTab = styled(Tab)({
  "&.Mui-selected": {
    color: "red"
  }
});

<StyledTab label={tab.label} />
```

[image: Edit friendly-dewdney-ypg0tz]

Comment: Thanks man!! This is THE solution. I also change added
TabIndicatorProps={{ hidden: true }} on <Tabs ... /> component

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I found is to use the sx props to customize the default tab font color theme.

```js
<TabList
  value={value}
  aria-label="example"
  sx={{
  ".Mui-selected": {
  color: `orange`,
  },
  }}>
                
    <Tab />                
    <Tab />     
 </TabList>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try override with this way

```
let theme = useTheme();

theme = createTheme(theme, {
    components: {
      MuiTab: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root:{
            "&.Mui-selected": {
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
              color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
              borderRadius: "25px"
            }
          }
        }
          }
        }
      })
```

it can be hellpfull [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui3-how-to-override-tab-theme-forked-m6z76?file=/demo.js:882-1082)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with this,  I found that the fastest way would be to identify the classes in use - inspect element -  then override them directly using CSS.
`.MuiTab-root{ color: maroon !important; }`